# How to make a custom stack on Eclipse-Che for Node-Red module?

Tags: node.js, node-red, eclipse-che

I want to make a custom stack for eclipse che for node-red.

Can anybody tell me the detailed procedure?

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't work that way. You need to try, and when you get stuck ask a question showing what you've tried and explaining how it doesn't work and somebody will help you fix it. Asking for tutorials is listed as off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I tried every possible way before asking. As of now I have success in preparing a stack for che.

Comment: But you've not shown us what you tried, so we can't help you fix it...

Answer (score 1):

The stack notion was used for old Che 6.x.

For Che 7.x it is a devfile [1] 
Read the doc how to configuring your workspace using a devfile [2]

[1] https://redhat-developer.github.io/devfile/

[2] https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/configuring-a-workspace-using-a-devfile/